# Python - put several ticks in one place

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to have several ticks in one place, like in the picture shown below.

[image]

I.e. instead of one small vertical segment I wish to have two or three or more around a specific location on the axis.
How can i achive this?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I mean not one small vertical segment but two or three or more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use minor ticks to produce the additional ticks. Their location can be specified using a [`FixedLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator). You can then adapt their style to match the one of the major ticks by obtaining the respective [rcParams](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker

plt.plot([0,5],[1,1])
locs= [3.95,4.05] + [4.9,4.95,5.05,5.1]

plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator( locs ))
plt.gca().tick_params('x', length=plt.rcParams["xtick.major.size"], 
                           width=plt.rcParams["xtick.major.width"], which='minor')

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

The problem with the above is that it is scale dependent, i.e. for a different scale e.g. from 4.8 to 5.2, the ticks would be much further away than desired.
To overcome this problem we can subclass the `FixedLocator` and have it return positions which are offset from the desired location by some units in pixels instead of data coordinates.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker
import matplotlib.transforms
import numpy as np

class MultiTicks(matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator):
    def __init__(self, locs, nticks, space=3, ax=None):
        """
        @locs: list of locations where multiple ticks should be shown
        @nticks: list of number of ticks per location specified in locs
        @space: space between ticks in pixels
        """
        if not ax:
            self.ax = plt.gca()
        else:
            self.ax = ax
        self.locs = np.asarray(locs)
        self.nticks = np.asarray(nticks).astype(int)
        self.nbins = None
        self.space = space

    def tick_values(self, vmin, vmax):
        t = self.ax.transData.transform
        it = self.ax.transData.inverted().transform
        pos = []
        for i,l in enumerate(self.locs):
            x = t((l,0))[0]
            p = np.arange(0,self.nticks[i])//2+1
            for k,j in enumerate(p):
                f = (k%2)+((k+1)%2)*(-1)
                pos.append( it(( x + f*j*self.space, 0))[0] )
        return np.array(pos)


# test it:
plt.plot([0,5],[1,1])
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultiTicks(locs=[4,5],nticks=[2,4]))
plt.gca().tick_params('x', length=plt.rcParams["xtick.major.size"], 
                           width=plt.rcParams["xtick.major.width"], which='minor')

plt.show()
```

In the initialization of the custom Locator, `MultiTicks(locs=[4,5],nticks=[2,4])`, we specify the positions where some additional ticks should appear (at 4 and 5) and the respective number of ticks (2 ticks at 4, 4 ticks at 5). We can also specify the number of pixels those ticks should be spaced from each other using the `space` argument.

[image]

Comment: +1, thank you, can i somehow do it in screen space? because othrewise i will have problems with scaling?

Comment: I was afraid you'd ask that. :-) This really is not easy. I will try to find a solution.

Comment: Soo, that did actually work out well. It may just be a little more code than expected.